# Average reputation/day for selection in reputation graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation, reputation-graph

It would be nice to see the average reputation for a selection in the reputation graph, because it's quite a job to calculate it manually.

[image: Average of selection - example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### [I've made a Chrome Plugin for it](http://github.com/haampie/Average-Reputation-for-Stack-Exchange-websites)

Credits for Yi Jiang

Answer (score 2):

Well, for now you can use this instead :)

```
var t = 0, 
    start = new Date($('#start-date').val()), 
    end = new Date($('#end-date').val());

$('.repcell .grpos').each(function(){
    t += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
});

console.log('Average rep gain per day: ' + (t / ((end - start)/(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24))));
```

Comment: Haha, nice solution :] I'll make a Chrome plugin for this :]

Comment: I made a Chrome plug-in for it, if someone else is interested I'll post it on meta in a separate topic.

Comment: I'm getting `NaN` as a result, possibly because of changes to the way the rep page works.